# Gluing two continuous functions to form another continuous function

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

I was checking an exam I did long ago, and want to ask about this question:
Let $a<b<c$ . Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ , let $g$ be continuous on $[b,c]$ and suppose $f(b)=g(b)$ . We define $h(x)$ on $[a,c]$ by :
$$h(x) =
\begin{cases}
f(x)  & \text{if $a\le x\le b$} \\
g(x) & \text{if $b\lt x\le c$}
\end{cases}$$
Show that the function $h$ is continuous in $[a,c]$ .

So this is what I wrote:
We know that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, so the function $h$ is also continuous on that interval. Now, by definition, $g$ is said to be continuous on $[b,c]$ if $g$ is also continuous on $(b,c)$, and because we define $g$ to be continuous on such interval, and $f(b)=g(b)$  then $h(x)$ is continuous in $[a,c]$. What do you think about this proof? Can you see any flaw here?

Comment: You did not prove continuity at $b$ at all. That is the main thing to be proved.

Comment: Have you heard of the Pasting Lemma?

Comment: @K.Jiang A little

Comment: To this problem, what is the definition you are to use for "continuity"? Once you know that, try to apply it to the point where the domains of $f$ and $g$ coincide.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $h(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b)$ and $(b, c]$. The final thing to do is prove that $h(x)$ is continuous at $x = b$. In other words, prove that
$$
\lim_{x \to b} h(x) = h(b)
$$
We can calculate the limit from each side:
$$
\lim_{x \to b^+} h(x) \\
= \lim_{x \to b^+} g(x) = g(b) \text{  (Since $g(x)$ is right-continious at $b$)}
$$

$$
\lim_{x \to b^-} h(x) \\
= \lim_{x \to b^-} f(x) = f(b) \text{  (Since $f(x)$ is left-continious at $b$)}
$$
Since $f(b) = g(b)$, we have
$$
\lim_{x \to b^-} h(x) = \lim_{x \to b^+} h(x) = f(b) = g(b) = h(b) \\
\Rightarrow \lim_{x \to b} h(x) = h(b)
$$

Answer (score 1):

$h$ is clearly continuous at every point in $[a, c] - \{ b \}$. To show that $h$ is continuous at $x = b$, consider some arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$. By the continuity of $f$, we are guaranteed some $\delta_1 > 0$ such that if $d (x, b) < \delta_1$, then $d (f (x), f (b) = h (b)) < \varepsilon$. In a similar way, by the continuity of $g$, there exists some $\delta_2 > 0$ such that if $d (x, b) < \delta_2$, then $d (g (x), g (b) = h (b)) < \varepsilon$.

Take $\delta = \min \{ \delta_1, \delta_2 \}$. Note that if $d (x, b) < \delta$, then clearly $d (x, b) < \delta_1$ and $d (x, b) < \delta_2$. By the above, this implies that $d (f (x), h (b))$ and $d (g (x), h (b))$ are both smaller than $\varepsilon$. Since $h (x)$ is either equal to $f (x)$ or $g (x)$, this implies, either way, that $d (h (x), h (b)) < \varepsilon$.

Therefore, $h$ is continuous at $x = b$. Being continuous at each point of its domain, $h$ is continuous.